# Configuring a single and custom retry-topic for non-blocking retries in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm testing the new feature in Spring Kafka 2.7 for non-blocking retries. I have a fixed retry-topic that is already given and named after a certain scheme prescribed by my company, and no DLT topic. I want to configure a retry policy with a fixed backoff policy, no DLT, but with my single retry-topic. I couldn't find a way to configure this with `RetryTopicConfiguration`. In `RetryTopicConfiguration`, the name of the retry-topic is constructed by appending a suffix (depending on the `TopicSuffixingStrategy`) to the main topic name. Is there a way to set the retry-topic directly?

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies).

> **Custom naming strategies**

> More complex naming strategies can be accomplished by registering a bean that implements `RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory`. The default implementation is `SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory` and a different implementation can be registered in the following way:

```java
@Bean
public RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory myRetryNamingProviderFactory() {
    return new CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented a custom `RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory` which returns a fixed topic named `myretrytopic`. However, now I get the following exception when I run my application with my custom bean. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key myretrytopic (attempted merging values DestinationTopic{destinationName='myretrytopic', ...`

Comment: You appear to be declaring the topic as a `NewTopic` as well - remove that bean.